# In maven, can you disallow usage of transitive dependency in your code but still keep it in the classpath?

Tags: java, maven

There is a library A that depends on library B. My project has A as declared dependency, but that also pulls B into my project's classpath. How can I prevent classes from library B from being used in my project?

I know about dependency exclusion mechanism, but that's not an option since if I exclude B then the program won't work, as A relies on it. For the same reason maven-enforcer-plugin doesn't work either (at least the standard rules for it).

What I am looking for is a way to fail the build if packages from A's transitive dependencies are imported from my project's classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(a) Make A a compile-time dependency and exclude B in that stanza.

(b) Add B as a runtime dependency.

This has the effect you want, that is, B is not available at compile time but is included at runtime. No need to resort to an extra tool that checks package-based policies.

Here is an example (substitute groupId and version as fits your situation):

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>A</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                <artifactId>B</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>B</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Hm, haven't thought about that, but yest, it can totally work. In my particular case it's not exactly just one transitive dependency but more like a dozen or so, so it will be a bit of hassle though.. Thanks!