# disallow import of some transitive maven dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, ide, dependencies

With maven we can exclude some transitive dependencies.

But what if we need them at runtime, and still as architect I don't want them to be used and become API dependencies.

Is there tool to define and check for unwanted used dependency (i.e. imported in some Java class)?

A search here gives me hint for maven
[In maven, can you disallow usage of transitive dependency in your code but still keep it in the classpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27654832/in-maven-can-you-disallow-usage-of-transitive-dependency-in-your-code-but-still)

But that may be to laborious to define. Maybe IDE tools should be used?

**How to disallow import and use of some transitive maven dependencies?**
So that code will not be accessing different layers of our stack.
Yes, I understand that some educational work should go as well.

Comment: https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-lint-plugin is neither maven nor disallowing dependencies but it scans the actual dependencies in the code to figure out which ones are [unused](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-lint-plugin/wiki/Unused-Dependency-Rule). Maybe you could adapt that part.

Comment: Nice to know, but would need similar for maven.

Comment: I would suggest a deep look into http://jqassistant.org/ which can define such rules etc.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with maven there is a concept of dependency scope.  Typically for Java EE applications you will see 3 scopes leveraged the most:

**Compile** - This is the default scope used if none is specified.  These will be available in all of a project's classpaths.

**Provided** - This scope is used when the dependency is not needed for compilation, but is expected to be in the container at runtime.

**Test** - This is a dependency needed for testing, but not required for the normal use of the application

Based off of your use case I believe you are looking to leverage the provided scope for a dependency where the dependency is needed at runtime, but should not be available to the application during compilation.  You can read more about dependency scopes at:  https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

Comment: This will not prevent anyone to use a class from an implementation module which should not be used. In this case a class from the API module should be used instead.....

Comment: One solution to that situation is to package the Specification / API separately from the implementation.  Only have the implementation be available at run-time.  There are several frameworks that allow you do this.  Such as OSGI.